# js class returning undefined object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to import a class into a react class but when the object changes in the class it returns undefined.

```
class Test {
  constructor(){
    this.obj = {}
  }

  testFunc(){
    this.obj.one = 'two'
    // this returns the value
    console.log(this.obj.one)
  }
}

class App extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.testClass = new Test()
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.testClass.testFunc()
    // this returns undefined
    console.log(this.testClass.obj.one)
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? Are you saying `this.testClass.testFunc()` outputs `two` but `console.log(this.testClass.obj.one)` outputs `undefined`? because, removing the reactjs stuff from your code, it works just fine

Comment: perhaps your not seeing a `2` on the console output which would mean `two` was sent to the console *twice* - and the `undefined` is from something else ... try `console.log('in componentDidMount', this.testClass.obj.one)`

Comment: ok so if i do `console.log(this.testClass.obj)` chrome console will only show `{ }` but if i set a value in the Test class constructor `this.obj = {test:"test"}` that will show `{test:"test"}` in the chrome console

Comment: Could it be that you are not binding the `testFunc` method to your `Test` class? Try adding this line to your constructor:
`this.testFunc = this.testFunc.bind(this)`

Comment: still has the same result

Comment: in the chrome console the values show if i expand the object

Comment: Sounds like a typical async problem. You are accessing the property before it was set. Your actual code must be different. Please post a better example. But likely a duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/218196).

Comment: i think you might be right

Answer (score 0):

I think you missing render on App Component:

```
  constructor(){
    this.obj = {};
  }

  testFunc() {
    this.obj.one = 'two';
    // this returns the value
    console.log(this.obj.one);
  }
}

class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.testClass = new Test();
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.testClass.testFunc();
    console.log('value =>', this.testClass.obj.one);
  }

  render() {
    return <div />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I have done few tweaks. Your  code is working fine and returning the expected results.
```

you can check the fiddle:

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nadundr/z8qw5ynu/8/)

Answer (score -1):

I think, if you want to use `console.log(this.testClass.obj.one)` you need to return *`this`* key work in **`testFunc()`** function

Comment: The `this` in the expression `this.testClass.obj.one` refers to the instance of `App`. If you return `this` from `testFunc`, you'd get an instance of `Test`. Since `App` already has an instance of `Test` assigned to `this.testClass` and that is the *same* instance that `this.testClass.testFunc()` would return, it's irrelevant if it does return it or not.